# MVC 3 FormsAuthentication RedirectUrl and OpenID

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, openid

I have one View called SignIn that contains two partial views for authentication. One is for OpenID and the other is for logging in to my site using an internal account.

The Action for the OpenID form goes to an OpenIDSignIn() Action while the other just points to SignIn(). Everything works great except for when a user clicks a link to a view that requires them to be logged on [Authorize] etc..

I see the returnUrl in the QueryString however this value is not available to the current controller action, due to the fact that they will be either be logging in with OpenID or normally, thus caling the ActionResult associated with either of those views.

Just for clarification the returnUrl is the one that gets thrown in there from FormsAuthentication and is used when doing a RedirectFromLoginPage etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public ActionResult SignIn(string returnUrl)
    {
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
        {
            if(UrlUtil.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
            {
                Session.Add("ReturnUrl", returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("SignIn", "Account");
            }


        }
        return View();
    }
```

This seems to be a viable workaround. However I hate session variables!